# bitwise xor of all elements of A and that of all element of B is the same

Tags: algorithm

You are given an array A having  N integer You need to create a new array B having N non negative integer less than 2^25 such that bitwise XOR of all elements of A and that of all element of B is the same.   Find the maximum possible sum of element of array B modulo 10^9+7

input Formate : First line Contanins an integer.N denoting the Number of element in A each line i of the N subsequent lines (Where 0 <= i < N) contains an integer describing A[i].

Comment: Do not add irrelevant tags to your post.

Comment: No actucal this Problem Basically solve on C++ or Python

Comment: This is obviously homework.  You are required to make a good faith attempt to solve this problem yourself, and come to us if it doesn't work.

Comment: Tim Roberts I'm Not make Problem that's why i need some help on this Community

Comment: This is either a silly problem, or it is stated poorly.  Clearly, you'd want N-1 elements of B to be 2^24-1, and the Nth element to be the combined XOR of A, or the inverse of that, depending on whether N is odd or even.

Comment: What have you tried till now? Show us your attempt. We don't spoonfeed here.

Comment: I know sir You Are to Good in Problem Solving But I'm beginner  Roberts sir Please help me out sir ..

Comment: I've edited the tags to be just `algorithm` because the question, as currently stated, does not contain sufficient information to be associated with C++, Python, or Java. Once you've made [a good faith attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) in a programming language of your choice, feel free to retag.

Comment: Is that `Find the maximum possible (sum of element of array B), modulo 10^9+7` or is it `Find the maximum possible (sum of element of array B modulo 10^9+7)`? They're not necessarily the same.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this example with 8 bits.  Say that A is (in hex):

```
11
22
44
05
07
```

The combined xor is 0x75.  So, we start B with:

```
FF
FF
FF
FF
```

The combined xor of that is 0.  So, we just add the A result:

```
FF
FF
FF
FF
75
```

That set produces the maximum possible sum.  If the length is even, you have to use the inverse:

```
11
22
44
07
```

The xor sum is 70.  So B must be:

```
FF
FF
FF
8F
```

Comment: okay but You not write a code for this Particular Problem ... You Just a simple explanation

Comment: @PrabalPandey This is not a homework website. You need to understand and implement it yourself. *No spoonfeeding here*

Comment: Right.  This is not a code-writing service.  I have given you the exact algorithm, which is really the hardest part of this problem.  You need to write the code.

Comment: We expect you to [make a good faith effort to solve the problem yourself before posting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). If the explanation is simple, as you have said, you should not have any trouble translating it into a C++, Python, or Java program.

Comment: Okay I got it Your Point Thank You Roberts sir